# Hiding Specific Page in adobe Acrobat pro DC

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe, acrobat

> > Hiding specific pages based on a checkbox is unchecked and when checked it will show the page. Here's the script that I'm using but it is not working please help:

// Replacing "Checkbox1" with the actual name of your checkbox field

```
var checkbox = this.getField("Checkbox1");
```

// Replacing "PageNumberToHide" with the page number you want to hide

```
var pageToHide = this.getPageNthNum("PageNumberToHide");

if (checkbox.value == "Off") {
    this.hidePages([pageToHide]);
} else {
    this.showPages([pageToHide]);
}
```

Comment: It's possible but there's some setup involved and there are limitations. First, the pages you want to hide/show must be defined as "Templates". Once you have the templates, you can use JavaScript to set them to hidden or not however, when you "show" the page, it will be appended to the end of the document. You can't just insert it anywhere. If that's acceptable to you, I'll add an answer with the steps, the code, and a working file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the ("c1") with your button or checkbox name, change the template name ("2") to spawn your template, and lastly change the delete page number ("1") which page you want to delete.

**Delete page method is 0= page1, 1= page2 , 2= page3....etc.**

```
var f = this.getField("c1");
if(f.isBoxChecked(0)){
this.getTemplate("2").spawn();
   }
else {
     this.deletePages(1);
}
```